# converting & loading models in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm using Autodesk Fusion 360 to create some assemblies and I'd like to be able to display them using a three.js app.

Fusion can download any of the following formats: F3D (own format), Inventor 2014, IGES, SAT, SMT, STEP, DWG, DXF, STL (binary) & FBX.

My current workflow is Fusion 360 -> STL -> MeshLab -> OBJ & MTL -> three.js

This gives the following results:

- In Fusion 360: external faces are solid red, internal ones are white (removed this because I can only post two links)
- In MeshLab: [MeshLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89yXy.png) - faces are solid blue (actually, I didn't think STL carried any colour information, so I'm not sure how it has worked out that outside faces are one colour and internal faces are a different one) and otherwise it is an accurate representation of what I see in Fusion
- In three.js: [three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hexl4.png) - face colours are now shaded following the triangles.

Based on answers to other questions, I've tried using `object.geometry.computeVertexNormals()` and `mergeVertices()` in the `onLoad` function, but I get the error "cannot read property ... of undefined", which seems to mean there is no geometry object.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this the best workflow?
2. Is there a way to get real material info from Fusion to three.js?
3. How can I smooth out the faces?

Thanks.

Comment: The last image looks indeed like wrong or no normals applied. Instead of `computeVertexNormals()` did you also try `computeFaceNormals()`? And  maybe you don't need to convert it to OBJ. There is also a `STLLoader` in the examples folder.

Comment: That also doesn't work because the geometry object doesn't seem to exist. I have a version that works better in http://3dviewer.net/, but I created it before I was really noting my workflow and I can't for the life of me remember how it came about! `STLLoader` is on my list to try, but it creates a geometry without material and I can't see how I will be able to distinguish the different materials. Somehow MeshLab has done this, although it starts from the same STL file. I just don't understand the format well enough to know how that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you might be able to use the JavaScript viewer available here:

https://developer.autodesk.com/api/view-and-data-api/

It's extensible, uses ThreeJS, and provides full support for viewing Fusion models.